# Elasticsearch: Influence scoring with custom score field in document pt.2

Tags: elasticsearch

Having these documents:

```
{
  "created_at" : "2017-07-31T20:30:14-04:00",
  "description" : null,
  "height" : 3213,
  "id" : "1",
  "tags" : [
    {
      "confidence" : 65.48948436785749,
      "tag" : "beach"
    },
    {
      "confidence" : 57.31950504425406,
      "tag" : "sea"
    },
    {
      "confidence" : 43.58207236617374,
      "tag" : "coast"
    },
    {
      "confidence" : 35.6857910950816,
      "tag" : "sand"
    },
    {
      "confidence" : 33.660057321079655,
      "tag" : "landscape"
    },
    {
      "confidence" : 32.53252312423727,
      "tag" : "sky"
    }
  ],
  "width" : 5712,
  "color" : "#0C0A07",
  "boost_multiplier" : 1
}
```

and

```
{
  "created_at" : "2017-07-31T20:43:17-04:00",
  "description" : null,
  "height" : 4934,
  "id" : "2",
  "tags" : [
    {
      "confidence" : 84.09123410403951,
      "tag" : "mountain"
    },
    {
      "confidence" : 56.412795342449456,
      "tag" : "valley"
    },
    {
      "confidence" : 48.36547551196872,
      "tag" : "landscape"
    },
    {
      "confidence" : 40.51100450186575,
      "tag" : "mountains"
    },
    {
      "confidence" : 33.14263528292239,
      "tag" : "sky"
    },
    {
      "confidence" : 31.064394646169404,
      "tag" : "peak"
    },
    {
      "confidence" : 29.372,
      "tag" : "natural elevation"
    }
  ],
  "width" : 4016,
  "color" : "#FEEBF9",
  "boost_multiplier" : 1
}
```

I want to get the _score calculated based on the confidence values for each tag. For example if you search "mountain" it should return only doc with id 1 obviously, if you search "landscape", score of 2 should be higher then 1, as confidence of landscape in 2 is higher than 1 (48.36 vs 33.66). If you search for "coast landscape", this time score of 1 should be higher than 2, because doc 1 has both coast and landscape in the tags array. I also want to multiply the score with "boost_multiplier" to boost some documents against others.

I found this question in SO, [Elasticsearch: Influence scoring with custom score field in document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21439013/elasticsearch-influence-scoring-with-custom-score-field-in-document/21481792#21481792)

But when I tried the accepted solution (i enabled scripting in my ES server), it returns both documents with having _score 1.0, regardless the search term. Here is my query that I tried:

```
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "tags",
      "score_mode": "sum",
      "query": {
        "function_score": {
          "query": {
            "match": {
              "tags.tag": "coast landscape"
            }
          },
          "script_score": {
            "script": "doc[\"confidence\"].value"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I also tried what @yahermann suggested in the comments, replacing "script_score" with "field_value_factor" : { "field" : "confidence" }, still the same result. Any idea why it fails, or is there better way to do it?

Just to have complete picture, here is the mapping definition that I've used:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "photo": {
      "properties": {
        "created_at": {
          "type": "date"
        },
        "description": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "height": {
          "type": "short"
        },
        "id": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "tags": {
          "type": "nested",
          "properties": {
            "tag": { "type": "string" },
            "confidence": { "type": "float"}
          }
        },
        "width": {
          "type": "short"
        },
        "color": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "boost_multiplier": {
          "type": "float"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "settings": {
    "number_of_shards": 1
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**
Following the answer of @Joanna below, I tried the query, but in fact, whatever I put in match query, coast, foo, bar, it always return both documents with _score 1.0 for both of them, I tried it on elasticsearch 2.4.6, 5.3, 5.5.1 in Docker. Here is the response I get:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 1635

{"took":24,"timed_out":false,"_shards":{"total":5,"successful":5,"failed":0},"hits":{"total":2,"max_score":1.0,"hits":[{"_index":"my_index","_type":"my_type","_id":"2","_score":1.0,"_source":{
  "created_at" : "2017-07-31T20:43:17-04:00",
  "description" : null,
  "height" : 4934,
  "id" : "2",
  "tags" : [
    {
      "confidence" : 84.09123410403951,
      "tag" : "mountain"
    },
    {
      "confidence" : 56.412795342449456,
      "tag" : "valley"
    },
    {
      "confidence" : 48.36547551196872,
      "tag" : "landscape"
    },
    {
      "confidence" : 40.51100450186575,
      "tag" : "mountains"
    },
    {
      "confidence" : 33.14263528292239,
      "tag" : "sky"
    },
    {
      "confidence" : 31.064394646169404,
      "tag" : "peak"
    },
    {
      "confidence" : 29.372,
      "tag" : "natural elevation"
    }
  ],
  "width" : 4016,
  "color" : "#FEEBF9",
  "boost_multiplier" : 1
}
},{"_index":"my_index","_type":"my_type","_id":"1","_score":1.0,"_source":{
  "created_at" : "2017-07-31T20:30:14-04:00",
  "description" : null,
  "height" : 3213,
  "id" : "1",
  "tags" : [
    {
      "confidence" : 65.48948436785749,
      "tag" : "beach"
    },
    {
      "confidence" : 57.31950504425406,
      "tag" : "sea"
    },
    {
      "confidence" : 43.58207236617374,
      "tag" : "coast"
    },
    {
      "confidence" : 35.6857910950816,
      "tag" : "sand"
    },
    {
      "confidence" : 33.660057321079655,
      "tag" : "landscape"
    },
    {
      "confidence" : 32.53252312423727,
      "tag" : "sky"
    }
  ],
  "width" : 5712,
  "color" : "#0C0A07",
  "boost_multiplier" : 1
}
}]}}
```

**UPDATE-2**
I found this one on SO: [Elasticsearch: "function_score" with "boost_mode":"replace" ignores function score](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32732166/elasticsearch-function-score-with-boost-modereplace-ignores-function-sco)

It basically says, if function doesn't match, it returns 1. That makes sense, but I'm running the query for the same docs. That's confusing.

**FINAL UPDATE**
Finally I found the problem, stupid me. ES101, if you send GET request to search api, it returns all documents with score 1.0 :) You should send POST request... Thx a lot @Joanna, it works perfectly!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may try this query - it combines scoring with both: `confidence` and `boost_multiplier` fields:

```
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
        "query": {
            "bool": {
                "should": [{
                    "nested": {
                      "path": "tags",
                      "score_mode": "sum",
                      "query": {
                        "function_score": {
                          "query": {
                            "match": {
                              "tags.tag": "landscape"
                            }
                          },
                          "field_value_factor": {
                            "field": "tags.confidence",
                            "factor": 1,
                            "missing": 0
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                }]
            }
        },
        "field_value_factor": {
            "field": "boost_multiplier",
            "factor": 1,
            "missing": 0
        }
      }
    }
}
```

**When I search with `coast` term - it returns:**

- document with `id=1` as only this one has this term, and the scoring is `"_score": 100.27469`.

**When I search with `landscape` term - it returns two documents:**

- document with `id=2` and scoring "_score": 85.83046
- document with `id=1` and scoring "_score": 59.7339

As document with `id=2` has higher value of `confidence` field, it gets higher scoring.

**When I search with `coast landscape` term - it returns two documents:**

- document with `id=1` and scoring "_score": 160.00859
- document with `id=2` and scoring "_score": 85.83046

Although document with `id=2` has higher value of `confidence` field, document with `id=1` has both matching words so it gets much higher scoring. By changing the value of `"factor": 1` parameter, you can decide how much `confidence` should influence the results.

#### boost_muliplier field

More interesting thing happens when I index a new document: let's say it is almost the same as document with `id=2` but I set `"boost_multiplier" : 4` and `"id": 3`:

```
{
  "created_at" : "2017-07-31T20:43:17-04:00",
  "description" : null,
  "height" : 4934,
  "id" : "3",
  "tags" : [
    ...
    {
      "confidence" : 48.36547551196872,
      "tag" : "landscape"
    },
    ...
  ],
  "width" : 4016,
  "color" : "#FEEBF9",
  "boost_multiplier" : 4
}
```

Running the same query with `coast landscape` term returns three documents:

- document with `id=3` and scoring "_score": 360.02664
- document with `id=1` and scoring "_score": 182.09859
- document with `id=2` and scoring "_score": 90.00666

Although document with `id=3` has only one matching word (`landscape`), its `boost_multiplier` value considerably increased the scoring. Here, with `"factor": 1`, you can also decide how much this value should increase scoring and with `"missing": 0` decide what should happen if no such field is indexed.

Comment: thx a lot for detailed answer! when I try the query with coast, I still get both documents, and their scores are equal, 1.0. In fact, whatever I try as search term, it always returns all documents and their scores are all 1.0. I believe there is something wrong with the settings in ES? I'm using version 5.3.

Comment: I've updated the question with adding the response I get after running the query.

Comment: All works now, I was using get request instead of post :) Thx again for detailed answer!