# Score_mode avg returns 1 for all documents

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm using function score with score_mode avg and boost_mode replace.
And according to documentation I'm expecting the query function score to be overriden by the function score filters (because I'm using boost_mode replace).

This works as expected for the sum and multiply, but not for avg (I'm aware that the average in function score is a weighted average)

When I apply this function_score all the documents get a score of 1.

How can this happen?

```
GET kibana_sample_data_ecommerce/_search
{
  "_source": {
    "includes": ["customer_last_name", "customer_first_name", "customer_gender"]

  }, 
  "size": 10, 
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "functions": [
        {
          "filter": { "match": { "customer_last_name": "Cook" } },
          "weight": 2
        },
        {
          "filter": { "match": { "customer_first_name": "Jackson" } },
          "weight": 4
        },
        {
          "filter": { "match": { "customer_gender" : "MALE"} },
          "weight": 8
        }
      ],
      "score_mode": "avg", 
      "boost_mode": "replace"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this is a bit weird, but the link provided by @jzzfs is already pretty close. The average mode of the function score query provides a **weighted** average, which causes this [effect](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html):

> In case score_mode is set to avg the individual scores will be combined by a **weighted** average. For example, if two functions return score 1 and 2 and their respective weights are 3 and 4, then their scores will be combined as (1*3+2*4)/(3+4) and **not** (1*3+2*4)/2.

In addition, it's important to note that due to this, function scores whose filters don't match the current document **have no effect on the average score**, rather then reducing it. In your example, this means that if a document only matches by having a `MALE` customer, it will have a score of 8, but since it's weighted it'll actually have a score of `(1*8)/8 = 1`. If it's a `MALE` with the first name `Jackson`, the score again will be `(1*8 + 1*4)/(8+4)=1`. This can easily seen by using the [explain api](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-explain.html):

```
GET kibana_sample_data_ecommerce/_explain/ER5Bv3ABEiTwEf3FhKws
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "functions": [
        {
          "filter": { "match": { "customer_last_name": "Cook" } },
          "weight": 2
        },
        {
          "filter": { "match": { "customer_first_name": "Jackson" } },
          "weight": 4
        },
        {
          "filter": { "match": { "customer_gender" : "MALE"} },
          "weight": 8
        }
      ],
      "score_mode": "avg", 
      "boost_mode": "replace"
    }
  }
}
```

returns

```
{
  "_index" : "kibana_sample_data_ecommerce",
  "_type" : "_doc",
  "_id" : "ER5Bv3ABEiTwEf3FhKws",
  "matched" : true,
  "explanation" : {
    "value" : 1.0,
    "description" : "min of:",
    "details" : [
      {
        "value" : 1.0,
        "description" : "function score, score mode [avg]",
        "details" : [
          {
            "value" : 8.0,
            "description" : "function score, product of:",
            "details" : [
              {
                "value" : 1.0,
                "description" : "match filter: customer_gender:MALE",
                "details" : [ ]
              },
              {
                "value" : 8.0,
                "description" : "product of:",
                "details" : [
                  {
                    "value" : 1.0,
                    "description" : "constant score 1.0 - no function provided",
                    "details" : [ ]
                  },
                  {
                    "value" : 8.0,
                    "description" : "weight",
                    "details" : [ ]
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "value" : 3.4028235E38,
        "description" : "maxBoost",
        "details" : [ ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Stefano Branco, this looks a good explanation, I need to try this out. Never read about it but using the explain API is definitely a very good way to go. I'm mindblown by the possibility of this being truth...

Comment: Agree, this doesn't seem very intuitive to me either. There has been some [discussion](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/13732) about the average function a few years ago, and I think your issue would provide a strong case for possibly rethinking that behaviour.

Comment: Hi @Stefano Branco, only now I could test your theory. and I'm relutant about your answer. Maybe you can help me. using that same code, I found out that when no filter function is matched, the documents still have a score of one. you can test yourself, you will find documents like this. 
if none of the filters is matched. what is left for the math to work out and return 1? Something is missing in this puzzle

Comment: Looks Like I was finally able of understanding the Explain API ... and Looks Like I understood the missing piece of the puzzle. It complements what you have said. 
1) non matching filters do not count for the math.
2) if no matching filter than the score will be the minimum between 1 and maxboost, 1 is return. so this looks like a bug where we will always get 1 as result, unless you can change this default value for when a value is not matched. 

What do you think? It looks like this to me

Comment: Not sure if they designed it this way on purpose, but definitely does not seem to work they way it should. Because the average is **weighted**, and non-matching filters are excluded completely, the score will always end with a division by itself. So in the second example above, what I would want would be `(1*8 + 1*4 + 0*2)/(8 + 4 + 2)`, but since the final filter is excluded completely, it's also excluded out of the **weighted** query. In my opinion, this design just makes no sense for this specific case.

Comment: Hi @Stefano Branco, thank you for your contribution. This was really one of the big puzzles to me in Elasticsearch function_score

Answer (score 0):

It's already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32736329/8160318). Since you used `boost_mode:replace`, only the function scores are used & the query score gets ignored.
[image]

Based on that, since your weights are the same, they "cancel each other out" to result in 1.

Comment: Hello @jzzfs, That's true, I'll update my example because even if I change the weights I get 1, if I put 2, 4 and 8. I still get 1. I'll update the body

Comment: So what I mean is your logic is correct and works like expected and documented, but its stops behaving that what when you put different weights and you still get score of 1

Comment: Gotcha. Please add a few of your actual docs to question too & I'll test it myself.

Comment: Hi @jzzfs, if you have elasticsearch and kibana installed this is the vanilla kibana_sample_data_ecommerce index sample data. If not I can only post some documents at the evening as I've not acces to the environment as of now

Comment: Right. So I'd simply recommend to use `score_mode: sum` instead of `avg`. And it's always good to dig deeper using `/_search?explain=true`, as @Stefano Branco showed. Also, check https://stackoverflow.com/a/12430664/8160318 for alternative boosting techniques if this `avg` stuff gets too confusing.

Comment: It is a good tip indeed, we can also add in our query "explain": true! Yes, I know that adding sum will work but has someone spent time developing avg. I want to be able of understanding and used it. And I'll try to! I that moment looks like the puzzle is not completly solve I might be missing something, feel free to help!